# Using a constructor to set variables

Tags: php, class, object

When using a PHP class function, how can I set variables in the constructor using an if statement.

My goal here is I want to check the variable sent to the class object and then change it in the constructor using an if statement. The idea is that it can then be used in other functions.

For example:

```
class myClass {

    // sent variable
    public $variable;

    public function __construct($variable) {

      if($variable == 'bar') {
         $this->$variable = "foo";
      }
      else {
         $this->$variable = "bar";
      }
    }

    public function run() {
         return $variable;
    }
}


$class = new myClass("bar");
$run = $class->run();

// This should return foo
var_dump($run);
```

The problem is that when I run this, I get "NULL" when I var_dump(). I'm expecting to get "foo" though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not correct and it should be as below -

```
public function __construct($variable) {

  if($variable == 'bar') {
     $this->variable = "foo";
  }
  else {
     $this->variable = "bar";
  }
}
```

You have been using

```
$this->$variable = "foo";
```

To refer the member variable you need to do as

```
$this->variable_name (without $)
```

So all the functions where you have used the above syntax you need to correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
public function run() {
     return $variable;
}
```

should be

```
public function run() {
     return $this->variable;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so any time I reference a variable in the object I need to use $this->variable?

Comment: @user3143218 correct, it looks like you also have some issues in your constructor, see Abhik's answer